# Powershell check whether a file exists

Tags: powershell, csv

On Windows 7 x64, Powershell 3.0:
I have a directory where I download files to, this is done with a .csv file.
A sample of the files is:

```
008KS04.zip
008KS05.zip
008KS06.zip
008KS07.zip
008KS08.zip
008KS09.zip
```

I have a Csv, op wich this is a sample:

```
Documentnummer,Versie,Status,Geocode,IDS datum,Documentgroep (Omsch),Documenttype (Wrd),Tekeningnummer
550164,I,AB,008,26.03.2016,Themalagen OI,KS,008KS09.zip
550163,D,AB,008,19.07.2013,Themalagen OI,KS,008KS08.zip
550162,D,AB,008,19.07.2013,Themalagen OI,KS,008KS07.zip
550161,C,AB,008,19.07.2013,Themalagen OI,KS,008KS06.zip
550160,D,AB,008,19.07.2013,Themalagen OI,KS,008KS05.zip
550159,E,AB,008,15.08.2014,Themalagen OI,KS,008KS04.zip
```

So, lets say the files are in c:\test\
and the csv in C:\drawings.csv
I want the files that are missing in a csv, lets say C:\missing.csv
At first I tried with one drawing in a variable:

```
$drawnr = '008KS09.zip'
$destcsv = "C:\missing.csv"
Set-Location C:\test
    If(Test-Path -Path ${drawnr}) {
       Write-Output "${drawnr}'.zip' exists"

  } Else {

    Write-Output "${drawnr}'.zip' doesnt exist"
    ${drawnr} | Export-Csv $destcsv -Append -NoTypeInformation

}
```

[The output when having an existing and a non existsing drawing in the variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2RDK.png)
This works perfect, see image but using the CSV as input, I can't get it to work.
This is what I have so far:

```
$sourcecsv = 'C:\drawings.csv'
$destcsv = 'C:\missing.csv'
Set-Location 'C:\test\'

Import-Csv $sourcecsv | Select-object -Property Tekeningnummer | ForEach {

    Write-Output "${_} is the current object" #For Testing purpuse
If (Test-Path -Path ${_}) {

    Write-Output "${_} does exist"

  } Else {

    Write-Output "${_} doesnt exist"
    ${_} | Export-Csv $destcsv -Append -NoTypeInformation
    }
}
```

This tells me that none of the files exist, while all do exist.
See the picture to see the output of PowerShell and the content written to the missing.csv
[The picture of the output where all files are reported as non existend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkECe.jpg)

Comment: What if you change `Select-object -Property Tekeningnummer` to `Select-object -ExpandProperty Tekeningnummer` or alternatively change each `${_}` to `$_.Tekeningnummer`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I get your intent, but it looks like this might work.

```
$sourcecsv = 'C:\drawings.csv'
$destcsv = 'C:\missing.csv'
Set-Location 'C:\test\'

Import-Csv $sourcecsv | ForEach {

    Write-Output "${_} is the current object" #For Testing purpuse
    $TK = $_.Tekeningnummer
If (Test-Path -Path $TK) {

    Write-Output "$TK does exist"

  } Else {

    Write-Output "$TK doesnt exist"
    $_ | Export-Csv $destcsv -Append -NoTypeInformation
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if `${_}` is a new syntax I'm not aware of but I can't get it to work on my PS4 host so I'm changing that to the normal `$_` in my answer.  beyond that you just need to do an `ExpandProperty` as @DaveSexton suggests.

```
Import-Csv $sourcecsv | Select-object -ExpandProperty Tekeningnummer | ForEach {

Write-Output "$($_) is the current object" #For Testing purpuse
If (Test-Path -Path $($_) {

  Write-Output "$($_) does exist"

} Else {

  Write-Output "$($_) doesnt exist"
  $_ | Export-Csv $destcsv -Append -NoTypeInformation
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just do it ;)

```
$sourcecsv = 'C:\drawings.csv'
$destcsv = 'C:\missing.csv'
$dirtest='C:\test\'

Import-Csv $sourcecsv | where {-not (Test-Path "$dirtest$($_.Tekeningnummer)") } | export-csv $destcsv -NoTypeInformation
```